# jQuery ajax waiting php response process

Tags: php, jquery, phpmailer

I am using ajax function to send data. In php process I run phpmailer to send email using smtp gmail. Everything went well, but there are conditions where I want to make the information to the user to wait for the ongoing process. My code :

```
LoadingProccess();
var FormData = $('#subscribe').serialize(); 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "proses_corporate.php",
    data: FormData,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        var cek = data.result;
        $.unblockUI();
        if(cek=='Success'){
        $('#subscribe')[0].reset();
        $.blockUI({ 
            message:  '<h4>'+data.status+'</h4>', 
            timeout:   8000 ,
            css: {
              top:  ($(window).height() - 100) /2 + 'px', 
              left: ($(window).width() - 650) /2 + 'px',
              width: '650px'
        }); 
            setTimeout(function() { 
                window.location.href = 'http://www.domain.com/';
            }, 8000);
    }
      setTimeout(function() { 
          window.location.href = 'http://www.domain.com/';
      }, 8000);
    }
   },
         error: function() {
            alert('Error');
         }

});
```

Scenario : When I do submit, the application will be locked and display information to the user that the process is underway. For that php takes a few seconds to process the sending mail via smtp gmail.

In my php echo json_encode give to give orders to the jquery to display the information that the process has been successfully. My **php** code :

```
function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Username = GUSER;  
    $mail->Password = GPWD;           
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return $error;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return $error;
    }
}
```

Using

```
smtpmailer('bertho_joris@yahoo.co.id','berthojoris@gmail.com','GMAIL','Testing Form GMail','Test...Test...Test...Test...');
echo json_encode(array('status' => 'Data has been sent.', 'result' => 'Success'));
```

As in the above code, the form will be routed to a specific page after a successful process. In my case, how jQuery wait for the results of the dynamic php before turning the page?

Do you have to use a **timeout: 10000** on the jQuery? It seems not dynamic because the clock is set manually. Is there another way?

Comment: Do you want to redirect to another page on Success and show some error message if case any error occurred?

Comment: yes....But after php process

Comment: You can add an else block for "if(cek == 'Success')" statement and show error/redirect to another page in case PHP process does not return "Success"

Comment: I've made a block else but that if the process fails. What I mean in my question is the process of successfully

Comment: Sorry, but I still did not get your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you make your ajax request timeout longer when waiting response. e.g

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "proses_corporate.php",
    data: FormData,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 30000, // 3 second
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res){   }, 
    failed: function(err){   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put a mask on the page and make it visible on [ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and disappear or redirect the page on [ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) functions

Answer (score 0):

you can use the beforeSend function to add mask. 
and on Complete function remove the mask.